# Laravel route issue in subfolder

Tags: laravel

I have installed laravel 5.4 app at https://wolvecapital.com/muazzamazaz/

its getting web page of https://wolvecapital.com after login or register

For example inside web.php

`Route::post('/sign_in' , 'UserApiController@signin');` this should get web page inside `muazzamazaz` resources but it getting main website page

I have put public folder files at root of `muazzamazaz` and all other files inside `muazzamazaz/justcabbie` folder

path setting inside index.php is:

```
require __DIR__.'/justcabbie/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/justcabbie/bootstrap/app.php';
```

all other settings are not changed

filesystem.php is:

```
  'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

since files are also not being stored in directory

Comment: https://wolvecapital.com/muazzamazaz/login it is working , https://wolvecapital.com/muazzamazaz/sign_in this is also working

Comment: @KamleshPaul please use sign_in only at form not in URl

Comment: yes i know it is post and it is working i have checked in postman

Comment: @KamleshPaul what output you are getting

Comment: csrf token miss match